# How to use Adobe Illustrator Scripting for Artboard?

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to load my SVG-images as layers folder onto a current document. Somehow I'm able to manage it for new document by using the script below but what I need is that I want to import all my images to current opened document. Can someone suggest how I can change the script below for doing this task?

Script source code is:

```
function getFolder() {
  return Folder.selectDialog('Please select the folder to be imported:', Folder('~'));
}


function importFolderAsLayers(selectedFolder) {  
  // if a folder was selected continue with action, otherwise quit
  var document;

  var mm = 2.83464567; // Metric MM converter…  
  // Set the script to work with artboard rulers  
  app.coordinateSystem = CoordinateSystem.ARTBOARDCOORDINATESYSTEM;  

  if (selectedFolder) {
    document = app.documents.add(
      DocumentColorSpace.RGB,  
      width = 720*mm,
      height = 720*mm,
    );
    document  = app.activeDocument;

    var firstImageLayer = true;
    var newLayer;
    var thisPlacedItem;
    var posX=10;
    var posY=30;
    var count=0;

    // create document list from files in selected folder
    var imageList = selectedFolder.getFiles();

    for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
      if (imageList[i] instanceof File) {
        var fileName = imageList[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if( (fileName.indexOf(".svg") == -1) ) {
          continue;
        } else {
          if( firstImageLayer ) {
            newLayer = document.layers[0];
            firstImageLayer = false;
          } else {
            newLayer = document.layers.add();
          }
          // Give the layer the name of the image file
          newLayer.name = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf(".") );

          // Place the image on the artboard
          newGroup = newLayer.groupItems.createFromFile( imageList[i] );
          newGroup.position = [ posX , posY ];
        }
      }
      posX += newGroup.width;
      if(posX > (newGroup.width*16)) {
        posX = 0;
        posY -= newGroup.height;
      }
    }
    if( firstImageLayer ) {
      // alert("The action has been cancelled.");
      // display error message if no supported documents were found in the designated folder
      alert("Sorry, but the designated folder does not contain any recognized image formats.\n\nPlease choose another folder.");
      document.close();
      importFolderAsLayers(getFolder());
    }
  } else {
    // alert("The action has been cancelled.");
    // display error message if no supported documents were found in the designated folder
    alert("Rerun the script and choose a folder with images.");
    //importFolderAsLayers(getFolder());
  }
}

// Start the script off
importFolderAsLayers( getFolder() );
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `document = app.documents.add(...` ? This should prevent a new document from being created. The next line will assign the active (i.e. open) document to the `document` variable.

Comment: yeah i've tried this but then got error on the line below'

Comment: If by "the line below" you mean `document  = app.activeDocument`, was there an open AI file? If yes, was it in RGB colour mode?

Comment: got it got it. Thanks alottttttt.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove these lines from your script:

```
document = app.documents.add(
  DocumentColorSpace.RGB,  
  width = 720*mm,
  height = 720*mm,
);
```